# How to free reallocated memory? C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory

I'm trying to free memory that's reallocated but I get an error...

```
float * foo = NULL;
float * bar = NULL;

void update()
{
    ...
    foo = (float *)malloc( a * 2 * sizeof(float));
    ...
    bar = (float *)realloc( foo, a * 2 * sizeof(float));
    ...
    free( foo );
    ...
    // when i do
    if(bar != NULL)
    {
        free(bar); // <-- error at executing
    }
}
```

I get error: http://d.pr/mpBF and visual studio shows me the following file:

```
osfinfo.c
=========
void __cdecl _unlock_fhandle (
        int fh
        )
{
        LeaveCriticalSection( &(_pioinfo(fh)->lock) );
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the value of `a`-variable 0?

Comment: Do you do anything with `foo` between those malloc and realloc? Or do you do anything with bar between realloc and free?

Comment: It is funny... This code works fine here with my GCC... I think the cause of your problem is actually at one of the "..." sections...

Comment: This is not the cause of your problem, but allow me to say that `if(bar != NULL)` is kind of useless, since `free` performs no operation given a null pointer.

Comment: @TalPressman yes, I updated the code so you can see it. @ Juho yes, actually the code is not completely mine and I'm debugging because I get memory leaks T_T. @ André Puel , thanks for your testing

Comment: @aljndrrr The solution posted by bames53 is incorrect. If the call to `realloc` fails it will return NULL, and you will have no way of freeing the memory allocated by the preceding `malloc` call. David Heffernan's answer shows the correct way of handling `malloc` and `realloc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you realloc memory you should not free the old memory.

```
bar = (float *)realloc( foo, a * 2 * sizeof(float));
free( foo ); // <-- this is wrong
```

You want:

```
float * foo = NULL;

void update()
{
    ...
    foo = (float *)malloc( a * 2 * sizeof(float));
    ...
    float * bar = (float *)realloc( foo, a * 2 * sizeof(float));
    if(bar)
       foo = bar;
    ...
    free(foo);
}
```

Comment: This code commits the classic `realloc` error. If the call to `realloc` fails then you won't be able to free `foo` and the memory will be leaked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And of course, you don't have to check for `NULL` before `free` (but you do have to check after the `malloc` and the `realloc`).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan fixed. (I'm still leaving it to '...' to actually decide what should happen in case of an allocation error though)

Comment: @bmaes53 Good. I've removed my downvote, and also removed the spurious `if foo != NULL` check before calling `free`.

Answer (score 6):

```
foo = (float *)malloc( a * 2 * sizeof(float));
bar = (float *)realloc( foo, a * 2 * sizeof(float));
free( foo ); // oops, foo has gone
```

At the point at which you call `free(foo)`, `foo` is invalid since it was already freed when you called `realloc`.

The code should be something like this pseudo-code:

```
foo = (float *)malloc( a * 2 * sizeof(float));
if (foo == NULL) 
    return ERROR_CODE;
...
bar = (float *)realloc( foo, a * 2 * sizeof(float));
if (bar == NULL) 
{
    free(foo);
    return ERROR_CODE;
}
...
free(bar);
return SUCCESS;
```

Of course, since this is C++, you should be avoiding `malloc` and `free` altogether and  using `std::vector<float>`.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the [`realloc`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) call manages to *extend* the memory allocated by the call to `malloc`. In this case both `foo` and `bar` will point to the same memory address, and you're `free`ing `foo` somewhere before trying to `free` `bar` resulting in a double deletion.

You do not need to `free( foo )` at all because `realloc` will do that for you if the memory area was moved during reallocation. From the linked page:

> If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've passed a pointer to `realloc()`, it is formally deallocated (freed) and you must not free it again.

> #### C99 §7.20.3.4 The realloc function
>
> 2 The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a
>   pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size. The contents of the new
>   object shall be the same as that of the old object prior to deallocation, up to the lesser of
>   the new and old sizes. Any bytes in the new object beyond the size of the old object have
>   indeterminate values.

It may happen that `realloc()` returns the same pointer as it was given, but you cannot assume that it will in general.  And once you've passed a pointer to `realloc()` (or `free()`) you must assume it is no longer a valid pointer.

The rules in C++ are basically the same; it incorporates the C89 standard for functions from C such as `realloc()`.

Your system is correct to complain that you're freeing unallocated memory.